# Peoplesoft campus solotion for third party developers

Tags: peoplesoft

How can I consume the web services that are available in peoplesoft campus solution? or anyone here knows where I can find the right resources on this.

Thank You in Advance.

Note: A quick google search didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Create or obtain the WSDL for the services then use that/those WSDL(s) to setup your consuming application.